# declaring new enum type php

Tags: java, php, symfony4, enumeration

I'm new to PHP and I'm working on Symfony 4 project

I've made a Java project using an Enum Class called role

```
public class Role {
public enum RoleEnum {
Admin, SuperAdmin, Etudiant, Entreprise } private Short id;
private RoleEnum name;

public Role(Short id, RoleEnum name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name ;
}
```

and in my user I made it like this

```
public abstract class User {

private Long id;
private String nom;
private String email;
private String mdp;
private String tel;
private String photo;
private Role role;
private Boolean etatCompte;
```

and I've made a relation between the two tables in MySQL

and I created this method in Java too

```
   public Role getRoleByName(RoleEnum input) {

    Statement stm;
    try {
        stm = cnx.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT id from role Where name='" +input+"'";
        ResultSet rst = stm.executeQuery(query);

        while (rst.next()) {
            Short id = rst.getShort("id");
            return new Role(id, input);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServiceEtudiant.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

and when I'm adding values to the table for example to add "admin" to the role I do it like this

```
        Role role = s.getRoleByName(Role.RoleEnum.Admin);
```

can anyone help me or guide how to do it the sameway in my symfony project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you can create associative arrays like:

```
[
    "FIRST" => 1,
    "SECOND" => 2,
    "THIRD" => 3,
    "FOURTH" => 4,
]
```

An improvement on this is to create the keys as variables as well:

```
$FIRST = "FIRST";
$SECOND = "SECOND";
$THIRD = "THIRD";
$FOURTH = "FOURTH";

$myenum = [
    $FIRST = 1,
    $SECOND = 2,
    $THIRD = 3,
    $FOURTH = 4,
];
```

You can create an enum generator

```
class MyEnum {
    public function __construct($keysValues) {
        foreach ($keysValues as $key => value) $this->{$key} => $value;
        $this->values = $values;
    }
}
```

Instantiation:

```
$numbers = new MyEnum(
[
    "FIRST" => 1,
    "SECOND" => 2,
    "THIRD" => 3,
    "FOURTH" => 4,
]);
```